# How to fix the border and padding on the links

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm trying to fix the lines of links on page I'm editing, I can't directly edit the HTML, and can only edit the CSS. For what ever reason no matter what I do, the line of text for a link spills into the other rows.

The result should look something like this:

[image: correct look]

But I get this:

[image]

```css
body {
    max-width:1122px;
    min-width:1122px;
}
.free_column{
    float:left;
    width:345px;
    height:315px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:12px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border:#d9d9d9 4px solid;

}
.free_column header{
    padding:14px;
}
.free_column h2{
    font-size:1.3em;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Subrayada', sans-serif;
    font-weight:200;
}
.free_column h3{
    font-size:.9em;
    color:#c3c2cc;
}
.free_column a{
    /*padding-left:64px;*/
    /*padding-right:150px;*/
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-left:18px;
    text-align:left;
    color:#667cbd;
    line-height:2.9em;
    border-top: #d1d1d1 2px dotted;
    padding-top:11px;
    font-size:1em;
}

.free_column header{
    background-color:#9f310e;

}
```

```html
<section class="free_column">
    <header>
        <h2>Free Enterprise</h2>
        <h3>Free Enterprise - Your Home for Free Market News and Ideas</h3>
    </header>
    <a class="free_links" href="#">Military, Government, Business: Working Together</a>
    <a class="free_links" href="#">’Tis the Season for … Dangerous Fakes?</a>
    <a class="free_links" href="#">A Regulatory System That Works for America, Part II</a>
    <a class="free_links" href="#">The Fourth Branch of Government, Part I</a>
    <a class="free_links" href="#">Reducing Poverty and Raising Prosperity</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Must each link's text be only on a single line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` elements are inline elements, they will only be as wide as their contents and won't always be box shaped, you can override this behaviour with:

```
.free_column a{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Update the `.free_column a` rules.

The `display: block;` transform it into a block element to fill the entire row.

```
.free_column a {
  border-top: 2px dotted #d1d1d1;
  color: #667cbd;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

Remove the `height` from the `.free_column` class.

Add `border-top: none;` to the first link.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4znkyroa/